# optimizing the sql query by not repeating the math

Tags: sql, oracle, math, case

Here is the query in Oracle I was trying to remove the redundant math operation from:

SELECT name,

```
     CASE 
       when nvl(num1,0) + nvl(num2,0) - nvl(num3,0) > 0
       THEN nvl(num1,0) + nvl(num2,0) - nvl(num3,0)
       ELSE 0
      END
      as result,
      .... from ....
```

How do I not repeat the summation above?

The 'result' should contain - value of the above expression if > 0

```
                    -  0 if the value of expression is <= 0.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's actually causing a problem in the query? Change the THEN to be a 1 instead of the summation and see if it actually makes a difference.  Otherwise you're going through all this effort for nothing

Answer (score 4):

In this case you could replace your CASE expression with:

```
GREATEST( nvl(num1,0) + nvl(num2,0) - nvl(num3,0), 0 )
```

OrbMan's answer is more generally useful though.

Answer (score 3):

Use a derived table:

```
select name, nvl(CASE when sumall > 0 THEN sumall end, 0) as result
from (
    select nvl(num1,0) + nvl(num2,0) - nvl(num3,0) sumall, name
    from MyTable
) a
```

Comment: Why not make the subquery: `select nvl(num1, 0)+nvl(num2, 0) + nvl(num3, 0) sumof3nums, name from MyTable` ?

Comment: Hmmm why is the `nvl` needed in the top-level query? Is it actaully possiblef or `sumall` to be null?

Comment: @Frus: because there is no `ELSE` clause, the case statement will return `NULL` when first case does not match. It could be written with the `ELSE` clause instead, same result.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to get rid of the math for performance reasons, the best way to do this (from a DBA's point of view) is to create another column called `result`, then use an insert/update trigger to automatically populate it when a row changes, with the value you want:

```
CASE 
   WHEN nvl(num1,0) + nvl(num2,0) - nvl(num3,0) > 0
   THEN nvl(num1,0) + nvl(num2,0) - nvl(num3,0)
   ELSE 0
END
```

That way, the calculation is only done when required (on a row create/change) rather than on *every single read*. This amortises the cost of the operation on databases that are read more often than written (which, in my experience, is close to all of them).

Then your query becomes a simple and blindingly fast:

```
select name, result from ...
```

This method works because:

- the vast majority of databases are *indeed* read far more often than they're written; and
- disk space is cheaper than CPU grunt (compare the number of database questions regarding database performance against those regarding storage requirements - the former greatly outweigh the latter).
- database queries with per-row functions rarely scale well as the tables get bigger.

This is all assuming Oracle *has* triggers of course. I'm a DB2 man myself but I'd be surprised if Oracle was so brain dead it didn't have them. Then again, for all I know, maybe Oracle *still* can't distinguish between NULL and an empty string, so who knows? :-)